# C# Sql Updating row by row from a List of Objects

Tags: c#

```
public int UpdateAmount(List<MyTable> myBizObjList)
     {
         SqlTransaction sqltxn;
         DbClass db = new DbClass();
         SqlConnection cs;
         cs = db.GetConnection();

         string commandText = @"Update MyTable Set amt = @amt  where empno = @empno and mydate = @mydate";

         int x = myBizObjList.Count;
         int y = 0,rowsaffected;
         cs.Open();

         using (cs)
         {
             sqltxn = cs.BeginTransaction();
             foreach (MyTable myBizObj in myBizObjList)
              { 
                 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, cs, sqltxn);
                 command.Parameters.Add("@empno", SqlDbType.Int);
                 command.Parameters["@empno"].Value = myBizObj.Empno;
                 command.Parameters.Add("@mydate", SqlDbType.Date);
                 command.Parameters["@mydate"].Value = myBizObj.Mydate;
                 command.Parameters.Add("@amt", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                 command.Parameters["@amt"].Value = myBizObj.Amt;
                                 
                 
                 try
                 {
                     rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     if (rowsAffected == 1)
                         y++;
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     throw (ex);
                    
                 }
             }
             if (y == x)
             {
                 sqltxn.Commit();
                 
             }
             else
             {
                sqltxn.Rollback();
                 y = 0;
             }
             cs.Close();
             return y;
         }
         
     }
```

Question: I am querying  a table and getting say 50K records which I am converting to a List of objects. I am processing the List in my BLL and sending to my DAL. The above is a method in my DAL. Is there a better way? I am also checking if all rows are updated & then Commit or Rollback.

Comment: Instead of updating record by record for 50K records, you can use the `user defined table type` and `stored procedure` to update all records at once in single transaction at Database end.

Comment: You need to dispose the transaction with `using`, also you should move `using(cs)` up to the setter `cs = ...`. Also you can shorten `command.Parameters.Add("@empno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = myBizObj.Empno`

Comment: Never do `throw ex;` where `ex` is a caught exception. You will lose your stack trace. Just do `throw;`. Of course...your catch block isn't doing anything at all except rethrowing, so it's entirely redundant and the try/catch should be removed from this code. There's also no need for `cs.Close();`, the using block will ensure that the connection is closed and disposed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for command.Parameters.Add("@empno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = myBizObj.Empno. One line less of code. So much to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this to a table-valued parameter.

First we need a table type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.MyTVP (
    empno int not null,
    mydate date not null,
    amt decimal not null
    primary key (empno, mydate)
);
```

Then we pass it through. You don't *necessarily* need a stored procedure, you can do this as an ad-hoc batch:

```cs
public int UpdateAmount(List<MyTable> myBizObjList)
     {
         var table = new DataTable();
         table.Columns.Add("empno", typeof(int));
         table.Columns.Add("mydate", typeof(datetime));
         table.Columns.Add("amt", typeof(decimal));
         foreach (MyTable myBizObj in myBizObjList)
             table.Rows.Add(myBizObj.Empno, myBizObj.Mydate, myBizObj.Amt);
         
         const string commandText = @"
Update tbl
Set amt = t.amt
FROM MyTable AS tbl
JOIN @tmp AS t ON t.empno = tbl.empno AND t.mydate = tbl.mydate;
";

         using (var cs = db.GetConnection())
         {
             SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, cs, sqltxn);
             command.Parameters.Add(
             new SqlParameter("@tmp", SqlDbType.Structured)
             {
                 Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                 TypeName = "dbo.MyTVP",
                 Value = table
             });

             cs.Open();
             return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }
```

Comment: command.Parameters.Add("@tmp", SqlDbType.Structured)
             {  Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                 TypeName = "dbo.MyTVP",
                 Value = table
             };                                         
 This section gave an error so I broke it:                                                       
  SqlParameter tvp = command.Parameters.Add("@UserDefineTable", SqlDbType.Structured);
                tvp.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                tvp.TypeName = "WageentryType";
                tvp.Value = dt; (This is working) Overall great.

Comment: Whoops sorry fixed. Note that I didn't use a transaction because it's all one statement